# How to get nodes matching multiple attributes with specific value?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

To get nodes by one attribute we can do:

```py
# root is an instance of etree._Element
nodes = root.findall('person[@city="NY"]')
```

But, how to get nodes filtered by multiple attributes?

```py
nodes = root.findall('person[@city="NY" @gender="M"]')
```

This didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
nodes = root.findall('person[@city="NY"][@gender="M"]')
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I resolved the issue differently. If somebody can confirm, I will accept as the correct answer.